# Turtle graphics crashing in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to use the `turtle` module in Jupyter notebook, however it's always crashed after running the code.

Could anyone please tell me how to solve this?

[image: screenshot of turtle window with a not responding message]

Comment: The problem may be your turtle graphics code—please edit your question and provide a [mre].

Comment: In turtle, if the code doesn't make 'updates', it will tell you the window isn't responding until you will 'update' the code

Comment: Are you making sure that you are using `turtle.mainloop()` at the end of the code or `turtle.update()` in a loop?

Comment: You may have a `while True:` hanging the screen.  Please share the code.